# Research Interest or Research Interests as a subsection title in a CV

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

I would like to know the correct/common usage of "Research Interest" or "Research Interests", especially when used as a sub-section in a CV or resume. Should I use the singular or plural form? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. One line questions are discouraged on this site. Have a look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Do you have a single interest or multiple interests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Interest" is being used as a countable noun in this context. So if you have several interests, then use the plural.  If your research is focused on one area, then use the singular.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have multiple interests, so I will use it plural.